# Concatenate duplicate rows with additional info (MySQL)

Tags: mysql, duplicates, concatenation

So I'm looking for an MySQL command to deduplicate rows in a table like this:

```
ID   origin   firstname   lastname   job         alternative_origin
1    table0   Andrew      Miller     Plumber
2    table1   Andrew      Miller     plumb.
3    table0   Joe         Armstrong  Taylor
4    table1   Phil        Marshall   Carpenter
```

I would like to concatenate all those rows where firstname AND lastname are identical so the table looks like this:

```
ID   origin   firstname   lastname   job         alternative_origin
1    table0   Andrew      Miller     Plumber     table1
3    table0   Joe         Armstrong  Taylor
4    table1   Phil        Marshall   Carpenter
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What should happen if there are 3 or more copies of Andrew Miller?

Comment: I have already looked at the duplicate records and i don't have any of these cases. Ideally, in the future, it would just add that information into the "alternative" column, like: "table1table2", if I ever add additonal tables.

Comment: Are you asking for a SELECT query, or do you want to modify the data in the table?

Comment: I would like to modify the data in the table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this sample data where there can not exist more than 2 duplicates for each name, use this:

```
update tablename t 
inner join tablename tt 
on tt.firstname = t.firstname and tt.lastname = t.lastname and tt.id > t.id
set t.alternative_origin = tt.origin;
```

to update the table and then delete the duplicate rows:

```
delete t
from tablename t inner join tablename tt 
on tt.firstname = t.firstname and tt.lastname = t.lastname and tt.id < t.id;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=6bf984bc3102fca2c70fe9e8eb5f42f8).
Results:

```
> ID | origin | firstname | lastname  | job       | alternative_origin
> -: | :----- | :-------- | :-------- | :-------- | :-----------------
>  1 | table0 | Andrew    | Miller    | Plumber   | table1            
>  3 | table0 | Joe       | Armstrong | Taylor    | null              
>  4 | table1 | Phil      | Marshall  | Carpenter | null
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I'll try it

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, the project hit a road block. However, worked like a charm, thanks.